# SVG/VML browser compatibility table

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, vml

I'm interested in finding a browser compatibility table that lists the parts of SVG/VML supported by each version of Opera, Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer (also Konqueror would be nice) in the vein of [Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/).

I have found the following two compatibility tables for SVG but neither of them provide enough detail:

- http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG&statuses=rec
- http://www.codedread.com/svg-support.php

The information in the first link seems to clash with libraries like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com) which claim to fully support animations in Firefox 3.0+ and Safari 3.0+ whilst the link suggests that the animation module isn't implemented till later versions for those two browsers.

The second link simply doesn't go far back enough for me to be able to draw conclusions about which features of SVG/VML I can use to ensure compatibility with older browsers.

Needless to say I'm endlessly confused.

To be perfectly clear, I'm interested in finding out which part of SVG are supported in different versions of all the popular browsers. As IE doesn't support SVG I'm interested in finding out which parts of VML the are supported in the different versions of IE.

If the developers of the libraries have found this information it must exists, it just seems to be evading me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is a difference between supporting animations in SVG and SMIL animations. SMIL is a declarative way of specifying animations. There was a bunch of vendor kickback about supporting it. The other method was to do animation via the SVG DOM. This has wider browser support.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this article helpful:

Creating SVG vector graphics for maximum browser compatibility
http://voormedia.com/blog/2012/10/creating-svg-vector-graphics-for-maximum-browser-compatibility

It shows some good examples of SVG features which aren't even supported by the latest versions of Chrome.

There's also a nice compatibility table at the bottom.